# DASH Streaming ExoPlayer android studio

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, video-streaming, firebase-storage, exoplayer2.x, android-studio-3.4

I'm streaming video from URL stored in firebase storage and I'm using the following code for streaming the video using ExoPlayer

```
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
LoadControl loadControl = new CustomLoadControl();
exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(SafetyTVHomeActivity.this, trackSelector, loadControl);
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videourl);
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
exoPlayer.addListener(new PlayerEventListener());
exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource, false, false);
exoPlayer.seekTo(0, 0);
```

Everything is fine and the video gets streamed. But the problem I'm facing is the initial load time to start the video is too long (5+ seconds). I want to reduce the initial loading time to start the video to (0-2 seconds). Is there a way to achieve this using exoplayer?

I also tried using DASH media source in exoplayer using the code below

```
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videourl);
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(SafetyTVHomeActivity.this, "app-name"));
MediaSource mediaSource = new DashMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(videoUri);
exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
exoPlayer.addListener(new PlayerEventListener());
```

I used the same firebase storage URL in the dash media source but I'm getting the following error

```
ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT G@��B�%���������...@2:79 in java.io.InputStreamReader@c587547) at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:105) at........
```

Could anyone please help me on how can I work around this.

My main objective is to stream video from URL and the initial load time to start the video should be 0-2 seconds (The way TikTok does it). Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: @GiruBhai did you find any solution ?

Comment: @iamkdblue not yet